# Meaning of Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY in Android

Tags: android, android-sensors

I'm trying to figure out what the meaning of the output from gravity sensors means in Android.

I understand is the gravity applied in X, Y and Z, what I don't understand is the difference with accelerometer sensor.

I know gravity is a fuse sensor which uses gyroscope as well and others...but getting for example a value of 29.4 (9.8 * 3) in the gravity[0] sensor means that there is a force of 3G applied in the X axle?

So it would similar to use acceleration = SQRT(X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2) but more precise?

Thanks in advance! Guillermo.